# Meiosis pairing of chromosomes

Tags: sex-chromosome

How do the X and Y chromosomes synapse during the zygotene stage of when they have almost no homology between them?

Answer (score 1):

There is 'homology' at the [pseudo-autosomal region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoautosomal_region), a recombining region of the X and Y chromosomes.